# Can't get controller to parse JSON back to model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that has an action that is supposed to take a POST'ed json object:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProject(ProjectDetails project)
{
    return Json(project);
}
```

However, what actually gets returned is a new, empty project object. It doesn't seem to actually populate the project object with anything other than the ID (which comes from the url `mywebsite/mycontroller/EditProject/3` for example).

My `ProjectDetails` object looks something like this:

```
public class ProjectDetails
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Factor> factors { get; set; }

    public ProjectDetails() 
    { 
        factors = new List<Factor>();
    }

    public ProjectDetails(Project p)
    {
        ID = p.PrjID; 
        Name = p.Name;
        Date = p.PrjDate;
        factors = p.factors;
    }
}
```

And JavaScript code to post looks like this:

```
    function save() {
        var data = {
            ID: 4,
            Name: "foo",
            Date: Date.now(),
            factors: []
        };

        $.ajax(window.location.href, {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ project: data }),
            success: function () {
                alert("done");
            }
        });
    }
```

I've been messing around with variations on this for a couple of hours and it stubbornly ignores the post data I sent and instead builds a new `ProjectDetails` with only the `ID` defined.

Any ideas?

I've even tried using the JSON data produced by the GET request to the same controller and sending it straight back (so it's gotta be in the right format, right?) and it still ignores it.

**Update**

Looking at this a bit more, my request is being sent as `application/json`, but when I set a break point in my controller and check the request, it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I can find my json string in `Request.Form[0]`. But from everything else I was reading, this should *just work*. I shouldn't have to retrieve the json string and deserialize it myself. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it. Turns out that despite the fact that Firebug showed the request headers as being `application/json`, you have to actually explicitly set them in your AJAX settings by adding:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

*facepalm*